# Quotes inside string from MySQL db, turn into � marks (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

this is the string I have in my MySQL db, (TEXT),

```
Hello 'muffin'
```

the output when doing

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
<?php echo $row['text']; ?>
}
```

is

```
Hello �muffin�
```

How do I stop this, I want it to output the quotes normally? :( I have made sure it is not an issue with the font, therefore it must be  an issue with MySQL.

Comment: Wow... that is impressive... `mufifn` turned into `muffin` :-P (boooo you made a _ninja_ edit)

Comment: @neal LOL!... I think that the issue could be UTF-8, can you show the table structure?

Comment: I set the collation to utf-8_bin, nothing changed, before it was, latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: @King `SET NAMES utf8` is a query you send from php before you start making any queries. `mysql_set_charset('utf8');`

Comment: Need to change table and field collation

Comment: are you sure that these are normal quotes, and not something like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe)?  also make sure that the encoding header of your html file is set to the encoding actually used when printing the values you get from the db

Comment: `mysql_set_charset('utf8');` worked :D tysm

Comment: @Esailija, as your comment appears to be the answer here, please write it as an answer and get it accepted.

Comment: Using `mysql_query` in new applications is a very bad idea. Use `mysqli` or PDO unless you have a very good reason why you can't.

Comment: `mysql_query` has always worked like a charm for me, I've never used mysqli or PDO? Why exactly is it a bad idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

Before running any queries. This makes MySQL interpret the strings you sends as utf-8 and send you utf-8 back. Since your webpage is sending utf-8 headers (You wouldn't see `�` in this context otherwise), it only makes sense.

Here you can find more tips: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/995876)